# Trying to connect to a sqlite data base but receiving a (no such table) error

Tags: java, database, sqlite

The connection was working until I switched tables. I am trying to connect to the table ClientHistory but it is giving me a (no such table) error. I don't understand what is wrong because it connected to and displayed the table "Employee info" but gives me an error when I change the table to ClientHistory. Other people have asked this exact question but there is no definite answer.

I am very new at this so please explain assuming I know nothing.
Help will be much appreciated.

```
/** Connection connection = null;    
public ClientHistory() {
    initialize();
}
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.0
 */
private void initialize() {
    connection = SQALimportThings.dbConnector();
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 655, 394);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(46, 94, 583, 216);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    JButton btnTheVibe = new JButton("Click Here For History");
    btnTheVibe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {


            try {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM ClientHistory WHERE name like ?";
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                pst.setString(1, ClientHistory.getText()+"%");

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The error statement probably doesn't lie. Open the database file - check if the table exists

Comment: cricket_007 I only have 2 tables, ClientHistory does exist?

Comment: Show the code that opens the connection.

Comment: Are you confusing database with table?